# Android Chrome and intents detections

Tags: javascript, android, html, android-intent, intentfilter

On Android, there are intents for apps as seen here:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.html

So if I have URL scheme www.google.com/calendar, Calendar app will be opened, etc.

However, I have question where/when this detection happens? I have experienced that tapping on the URL with supported scheme will cause intents recognition and if the scheme is recognised, the associated app will be opened. However, if I do redirection (javascript) to this supported URL in android Chrome, no recognition will happen so no redirection occurs. How can I build the URL in background (by tapping on the button), redirect to that URL and associated app will be opened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That feature called **Deep linking** in android. As per [document](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking.html) you can see

> Open the user's preferred app that can handle the URI, if one is
>   designated.
>
> Open the only available app that can handle the URI.

And for implementation you can refer this [link](https://android.jlelse.eu/deep-linking-in-android-46bc61bd9750)